XGBoost CV confusion on how to choose eval set
If I am using XGBoost with GridSearchCV, how should I choose my evaluation set? Note, I am referring to eval_set within the model params.
My current implementation is using GridSearchCV in order to optimize hyper parameters, however if I'd like to add early_stopping as a parameter I would require a validation set. From my understanding using CV, my current processes of using a training set for the training and tuning phase is fine, as CV deals with the validation component within the processes itself.
Another possibility was to use my testing set as my evaluation, however I am unsure if this will lead to data leakage/bias in my testing metrics.
